# C# Execute the catch block when the type is string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here I'm struggling to work with catch block like I wanted to execute the catch block when the value type is a string.

Here I'm using dynamic type to accept all the type of values when the method will returns.

Now I wanted to execute the catch block when the method will return the string type. 
Here my code is

```
dynamic paymentResult = null;
try
{
    paymentResult = await ExecuteSquarePayment(db, checkoutViewModel);
}
catch (Exception ex) when (paymentResult is string)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
        $"{Messages.DonationPaymentFailed} {checkoutViewModel.PaymentMethod} : {ex.ToString()}");
}
```

Comment: The `try-catch` block is for [handling exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch), you should just use `if (paymentResult is string)`.

Comment: In c# 6 we can define exceptions we can execute multiple catch blocks based on the condition by using when. reference <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6>

Comment: What exception are you expecting can be thrown in any circumstance when `paymentResult` isn't still `null`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a catch block for this. `try-catch` is used to handle exceptions. If it is an expected behavior just test for the `type`:

```
 dynamic paymentResult = null;

 paymentResult = await ExecuteSquarePayment(db, checkoutViewModel);

 if(paymentResult is string)
 {
      return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, $"
           {Messages.DonationPaymentFailed} 
           {checkoutViewModel.PaymentMethod} : paymentResult is a string");
 }
```

If for some reason you really need to do it in a catch block you will have to throw an `Exception`:

```
dynamic paymentResult = null;

try
{
     paymentResult = await ExecuteSquarePayment(db, checkoutViewModel);

     if(paymentResult is string)
     {
         throw new Exception("The result was of type string");
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex) 
 {
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, $"
           {Messages.DonationPaymentFailed} 
           {checkoutViewModel.PaymentMethod} : {ex.ToString()}");
 }
```

Comment: I'm thinking that he needs the `ex.ToString()` to show some business exception message from that `ExecuteSquarePayment` call.

Comment: Also, paymentResult won't get set if ExecuteSquarePayment throws, so the when condition could never succeed anyway.

Comment: You are right but how can I test dynamic type is a string when the return type is a string.

Comment: Just like I have shown. `if(paymentResult is string)` will be true if the result of `ExecuteSquarePayment` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you check in `ExecuteSquarePayment` for the correct type of the argument, right? If so, why not simply use the `catch block` with out the type restriction. If the argument type is correct there won't be an error.

I don't see any different `return` for other types that the argument may be.

Comment: ExecuteSquarePayment method will return dynamic type it means that method may return string, int or what ever

Answer (score 0):

I guess, if the ExecuteSquarePayment method throws an exception, paymentResult will always be null(not set).